# Calling WIFI settings (similar to AllShare app)

Tags: android, android-activity, wifi

After a couple of days of struggle i finally opted to ask for suggestions here.
I am creating an android app which requires WIFI connection.  So on entering the app i will be prompting user to switch ON wifi and i would like to show the user the "Default Wifi settings" present in android such that the user can configure network and connect to it.

I was able to create an intent to start Wifi settings activity without any problem. But what i want is the following

Requirement:  As soon as the user has connected to a particular network from the wifi settings activity, i would like to get back to my app activity without even the user pressing back button (This is implemented in AllShare app but i don't how).

Can anyone provide me suggestions to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Register a broadcast receiver in your Activity that will receive the establishment of Wifi connection and then bring your Activity again by start activity as a new task from the Receiver.

[Here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html) is a good example of broadcast receiver for Wifi

Comment: I tried the same but in that the receiver is unregistered in the onStop() of the activity.  If i unregister the receiver only in onDestroy then it will work but the activity is not guaranteed to be existing while the user is interacting with Wifi settings.  Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: If you need to bring the Activity no matter activity is in onPause or already destroyed then you can Register your broadcast receiver independent of Activity and can bring Activity from Receiver

Comment: I registered a static BroadcastReceiver to receive wifi state change, in the receiver i started MyActivity and i must have to add 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK' in the intent otherwise android will throw exception.  By doing this i satisfied my requirement but one more problem raised.  The problem is if i have opened my application and also wifi settings (default one in android).  In wifi settings if i go and connect to a network then the next moment my activity gets launched which shouldn't happen as wifi settings has been opened by user as separate app.  Still i couldn't find out the exact way :-(

Comment: You can register your receiver when wifi settings is launched from your activity and can unregister it when you get back to your activity or just unregister it in onReceive.